# How to SUMIF contains a partial string in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data frame which contains a list of items I want to sum if they are a partial match to another list. What I want to do is the following:

- Look through each item in list 1.
- Find all the items in list 2 which are a partial match to 1.
- Sum all those elements and insert into new column (i.e. sum of cost).

There is an implementation of this in excel I want to replicate in Pandas.

```
=sumif(b7:b32,"*"&b3&"*",c7:32)
```

https://www.webanalyticsworld.net/2014/07/using-ngrams-to-analyse-keyword-performance.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

sqr = pd.read_csv('Search terms report (7).csv', encoding='utf-8', skiprows=2, skipfooter=2, engine='python')

search_terms = sqr['Search term']

required_ngrams = 2

ngram_holder = []

ngrams = []

def generate_ngrams(s, n):
    s = s.lower()
    s = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ', s)
    tokens = [token for token in s.split(" ") if token != ""]
    ngrams = zip(*[tokens[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return [" ".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]

for x in search_terms:
    if len(x) > 0:
        ngram_holder.append(generate_ngrams(x, required_ngrams))

for x in ngram_holder:
    if x:
        for y in x:
            ngrams.append(y)

df = pd.DataFrame(ngrams)

df = df.drop_duplicates()
df.columns = ['Search term ngram']
sqr = sqr[['Search term','Cost','Clicks','orders','Online Sales']]

sqr
```

This code products 2 lists. One containing the list of keywords and the other containing the search terms along with the data.

What I want to do is sumif on the first list and pull in all items which are a partial match to the keywords in list2.

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.